# How can I locate and import excel files on jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am testing out some code for my research project that someone else made. When running, it asks which file I want to import. When I type in the correct file name and run it, I get an error message saying it cannot locate the file.

Any help is much appreciated, please note I am completely new to python and programming in general. Thanks!

Comment: You should add the relative path infront of the name. This has nothing to do with python but with operating systems.

Comment: How do I do this?

Comment: In unix something like 'path/file' would suffice, e.g. 'dir/subdir/myfile.txt'.